# Scanners exception: java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that accepts input from a file and prints a list of cities and their rainfall. I'm having trouble with the scanners that determine the lengths of the arrays need and the rainfall data for the cities.

I keep getting this Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
>       at BarChart.main(BarChart.java:29)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarChart
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //create scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //create size variable
        int size = scan.nextInt();

        //create arrays to hold cities and values
        String[] cities = new String [size];
        int[] values = new int [size];

        //input must be correct
        if (size > 0)
        {
            //set values of cities
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            {
                cities[i] = scan.nextLine();
            }

            //set values of the data
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
            {
                values[j] = scan.nextInt();
            }

            //call the method to print the data
            printChart(cities, values);
        }
        //if wrong input given, explain and quit
        else
        {
            explanation();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    //explanation of use
    public static void explanation()
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Error:");
        System.out.println("Input must be given from a file.");
        System.out.println("Must contain a list of cities and rainfall data");
        System.out.println("There must be at least 1 city for the program to run");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Example: java BarChart < input.txt");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    //print arrays created from file
    public static void printChart(String[] cities, int[] values)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<cities.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf( "%15s %-15s %n", cities, values);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460288/java-util-inputmismatchexception-error-when-scanning-from-a-txt-file

Answer (score 3):

In your file, if the size of the list is the only thing on the first line, in other words, like this:

```
2
London
Paris
1
2
```

then when you enter the for loop to read in the city names, the Scanner hasn't read in the first newline yet. In the above example, the calls to `newLine()` will read a blank line and `London`, not `London` and `Paris`.

Hence, when you get to the second for loop to read in the rainfall data, the Scanner hasn't read in the last city yet (`Paris` in the above example), and will throw the `InputMismatchException` since the city name is clearly not a valid `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460288/java-util-inputmismatchexception-error-when-scanning-from-a-txt-file/19460396#19460396), you should also check if there's another token that matches your desired pattern (int).

Check with [scanner.hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) before calling `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, and where the error occurs, most likely you are trying to read an integer, but the actual data that you are reading is not a number.

You could verify this by changing your `scan.nextInt()` to a `scan.next()` and printing out the value that you actually get. Alternatively, you could add “error handling” of the form:

```
       for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
          if (scan.hasNextInt()
            values[j] = scan.nextInt();
          else
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected token, wanted a number, but got: " + scan.next());
        }
```